# Docker container exiting immediately after starting when using npm init react-app

Tags: reactjs, docker, create-react-app

I am trying to start a Docker container with a react project, the project is created using npm init react-app.

This is my docker file

```
# Specify a base image
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install some depenendencies
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./

# Default command
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

`Docker build .` creates an image successfully (with a lot of npm warnings) and then when I run `Docker run <image>` this is the output in my terminal

```
> mytest@0.1.0 start /usr/app
> react-scripts start

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

Soon as it hits `Starting the development server...` it stops running in my terminal. If I check `Docker ps` I can see no containers are running, if I run `Docker ps -a` I can see a container was started up and then exited immediately.

`Docker logs` shows the terminal output above, anybody run into this situation? Its only with my npm init react-app project, my other nodejs + express projects run fine with the exact same docker file

Comment: Can you share the details of your `docker run` command pls? Are you using the `-d` flag?

Comment: To build `docker build .` it builds successfully and then I am just running `docker run <image>`. It works for my other projects just not for one created with `npm init react-app` I tried it in 2 different react-app repos one ejected and one normal, both dont work. Tried it in my nodejs + express api projects, works fine

Comment: The container will exit as soon as its main process exists. Try running `docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/usr/app -w /usr/app node:alpine` then at the prompt try `npm install` followed by `npm start run` (note: this may mess up your source directory so maybe backup your project first). You may get some helpful insights that way. Then, try the same thing but also with `-e SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` on the run line before the image name.

Comment: Use ```EXPOSE 3000``` in you Dockerfile and then try to build

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I tried downgrading but it didn't work. What worked for me is in `docker-compose` file in the react app sector I added:

```
stdin_open: true
```

This solution is also suggested here: [issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688)

Answer (score 27):

`docker run -it -p 80:3000 imagename` resolve my problem.

Comment: Based on the question I think this is the right solution since the question doesn't mention docker-compose.

Answer (score 12):

Running the command with `-it` worked for me:

```
docker run -it -p 3001:3000 Imageid
```

Answer (score 8):

I solve the problem. Inside package.json replace "react-scripts": "3.4.1" to "react-scripts": "3.4.0"

Then rebuild image and It works !
They mess up something with react-scripts": "3.4.1"
Just use version 3.4.0

Comment: This fixed it for one of my legacy packages, but I'll note that `4.0.0` and beyond has the issue fixed.

Answer (score 4):

So nothing is wrong with the setup turns out there is an open issue for this.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

Downgrading to 3.4 solves for now

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same issue. **-it** flag resolved the issue.

```
docker run -it -p 3001:3001 <image-id>
```

Comment: I downvoted because this is exactly the same as previous answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/61327560/735926 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/61004740/735926

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue as you and just ran the above command to fix it:

`sudo docker run -it -p 3001:3000 Image-Name`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below with **-itd** flag as well.

```
sudo docker run -itd -p 3001:3000 Image-Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion mentioned in this [ans.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67391044/9530790) on stackoverflow and on [github](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688#issuecomment-602084087), of adding

`ENV CI=true` to the Dockerfile before `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]`, worked.

I'm not sure why this works. It may have something to do with [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688#issuecomment-602149917) point. You can read more about the env `CI=true` in the react [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#continuous-integration).